# Showing images in a Circlular shape

Tags: android, geometry

I am fetching images from the server and they are in the square shape. But I want to show them in a circle in my application. I have tried it by making a Circle shape Drawable. But it is not working. Can anyone suggest me how this can be done.Any help would me much appreciated . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code:-

[Universal loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

```
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext()).defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
                .build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

    DisplayImageOptions options1 = new        DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisc(true).displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(60)).build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(Uri.parse(imgByURL).toString(), imgThumb, options);
```

or

```
imageViewUser.setImageBitmap(getCircleBitmap(bitmap));


import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
public Bitmap getCircleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        Bitmap output;
        Canvas canvas = null;
        final int color = 0xffff0000;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        Rect rect = null;
        if (bitmap.getHeight() > 501)
        {
            output = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            canvas = new Canvas(output);
            rect = new Rect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("output          else =======");
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 500, 500, false);
            output = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            canvas = new Canvas(output);
            rect = new Rect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        }
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawOval(rectF, paint);

        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth((float) 1);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried 2nd one. In that I am getting error for SRC_IN : "Not a field" .